# useState without events

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a beginner with React, and I'm learning the hooks.

```
export const BadgeSubojectivesCategoryCompletion = ({ themeToCompare, indexSkillCount, datas, src, titleSubobjective, descriptionSubobjective }) => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState([]);
  let errorMsg = "Error: ";
  const {data: countSkills, error, loading} = useQuery<SkillsDataResult>(GET_COUNT_SKILLS_DATA);

  if(loading){
    return 'Loading...';
  }
  if(error){
    return errorMsg.concat(error.name, ", Message: ", error.message);
  }

  const createNewMapOfDatas = () => {

    for (let i = 0; i < (datas.UserAchievements.length); i++) {
      if (datas.UserAchievements[i].label.localeCompare("categoryCompletion") == 0) {
        if (datas.UserAchievements[i].additionalInfo.localeCompare(themeToCompare) == 0)
          setStep(step => [...step, datas.UserAchievements[i].step])
        //step.push(datas.UserAchievements[i].step);
        }
  }
  return ;
  }
  const max = Math.max(...step);
  return (
    <div className={styles.BadgeProfileSubObjectivesMiddle}>
      <p>{countSkills.Category[indexSkillCount].CurrentSkillsAndDesires_aggregate.aggregate.count}/{max}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I would call my function createNewMapOfDatas to set the State of "step" array. But I have no event to do so. Are there a way to check if there are a change compared to the old array ? and so, call my function createNewMapOfDatas

Thanks for your future help

Comment: did createNewMapOfDatas is not called/run?

Comment: Question: how it's related to hasura?

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found the solution. I had to update the cache with some observables methods allowed by Apollo.

```
  const {data: countSkills, error, loading} = useQuery<SkillsDataResult>(GET_COUNT_SKILLS_DATA, {
    fetchPolicy: "network-only",
  });
```

The useEffect purposed by Giovanni was a good way as well to get datas properly. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is `useEffect` hook. So if you want to set `step` every time `datas` changes you could write something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
   createNewMapOfDatas();
}, [datas]);
```

Comment: Hmmm I did it, but it's the same. My values doesn't change if I don't refresh